# Display html content inside fancybox?

Tags: jquery, fancybox-2

I am trying to figure out how to display some html content below and open image in [fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/).
I've searched around but can only find how to display *only* html content inside the open window. I'd really appreciate any help. Thanks.
I've made a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jsykes/jzw5h55h/6/)

```
 <a id="single_image" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_s.jpg" width="400"><img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_s.jpg" width="100"></a>

<p>
Place this html content below the open image
</p>
```

The jquery

```
$("a#single_image").fancybox();
```

Comment: Your fiddle is full of invalid HTML (Extra closing tags and self closed tags. If you put `/>` at the end of the opening tag, you do not need an end tag. If you want an end tag, remove the slash) You also don't have an anchor with the ID `single_image`, like you're looking for with your JQuery.

Comment: Oh yes, apologies, I'll just fix that.

Comment: something like http://jsfiddle.net/outcgrjj/ or do you want to get the `p` content dynamically?

Comment: Well I'd like to eventually display some php variables but first I thought I'd see if I can place html below the image.I know that I can add a title but how about html content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've modified one of the example JSFiddles from their [tips and tricks](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#useful) section page to do what I think you're after.

Fancybox has a option to run some JS after the image has been loaded into their layout, we can use this to append your html of choice into the fancybox element.

```js
$("a#single_image").fancybox({
  afterLoad: function() {
    this.outer.append("<div>" + document.getElementById("content").innerHTML + "</div>");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>

<a id="single_image" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_s.jpg" width="400"><img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_s.jpg" width="100"></a>
<p id="content">
  Place this html content below the open image
</p>
```